# Padding a Number String with Zeros to remain as a Multiple of 3's in length

Tags: vba

I would like to have a quick single line VBA code to pad a number in string form to always have a length of a multiples of 3's.
For example:

"12" becomes "012"

"1234" becomes "001234"

"1234567" becomes "001234567"

"12345678912345678" becomes "012345678912345678"

and so on.

The number string will not have any fraction or decimal points, so not to worry about that.

The length of the resulting string should be a multiple of 3 by adding 0's to the Left.

The number string should remain a string throughout the coding and should not be converted into a number using a numeric function such as Val, as the original string could be very long over 150 digits and using a numeric function could truncate or round the number and give undesirable results.

I had come up with the following as a possible solution by checking the string length but feel there is a better more efficient way of doing it in one (1) coding statement.

```
Result = String((3 - (Len(MyString) Mod 3)) Mod 3, "0") & MyString
```

Comment: Shorter doesn't always equate better. What's wrong with the statement you've got there, and how do you "feel" it's inefficient? IMO what you've got is in the upper bracket of the level of complexity one wants to see in a readable statement that's easily modified/debugged. One improvement would be to factor out the magic `3` and make that a parameter to some `PadLeftInMultiplesOf` function (or any better name than that), e.g. `Debug.Print PadLeftInMultiplesOf(3, "1234")`

Comment: As I agree with the above statment, another method: `format(MyString, string((INT((len(MyString)-1)/3)+1)*3,"0"))`  But this will only work for numbers.

Comment: Or this that also works for other text strings: `Right(string(99,"0")&MyString,(INT((len(MyString)-1)/3)+1)*3)`

Comment: @ScottCraner I think `Int(.../3)` could be replaced by `...\3` (integer division) for fewer brackets and operations :)  (the `Format` method seems to fall apart with longer strings eg. `"1234567891234567812345678912345678"` though)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon did not know that, thanks.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon yup, apparently the limit is 29 digits.

Comment: OP: This looks very much like a [codereview.se] post, down to even the title describing the purpose of the code (kudos!) -- here on Stack Overflow, it's arguably opinion-based; enhancements of *working code* are best made on CR, where reviewers will provide feedback on *every* aspect of the code, so you'll want to present that code in its surrounding context "natural habitat" for best results.

Comment: Thank you all for the ideas. I have come up with one more possibility with one less bracket, but still uses a **double Mod** function. Still uses a double Mod Function: `MyString = String(2 * (Len(MyString) Mod 3) Mod 3, "0") + MyString `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts and your ideas, I have come up with the following using a single Mod Function:

```
MyString = String((Len(MyString) * 2) Mod 3, "0") & MyString
```

In general, a general formula would be:

```
MyString = String((Len(MyString) * (Multiples-1) ) Mod Multiples, "0") & MyString
```

Comment: examples of the use of the formula can be found here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224027/simple-number-to-words-using-a-single-loop-string-triplets-in-vba and here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223936/simple-number-to-words-using-a-single-loop-string-triplets-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1